# Printing multiple files from Nautilus

Tags: nautilus, printing, files, pdf

I tried to print multiple files. However not a single solution posted on the net works.

1. I tried a <kbd>right-click</kbd> using Nautilus actions as described in multiple posts.
2. Using the `lpr` command in the terminal and dragging files from Nautilus. Here print opens but files are held, and when the release button is pressed, the window closes without action.
3. With a script as posted here: [Printing a file from the right-click context menu in Nautilus](http://www.frenssen.be/content/printing-file-right-click-context-menu-nautilus%E2%80%8E)

The only method that works is combining pdf files in `pdfmod` to a new large file, saving it, and printing it. Not very elegant.

Since no option for multiple works, could the community have a fresh look at <kbd>right-click</kbd> printing from Nautilus?

Comment: Can you explain what it is that isn't working? I created a PDF printer just now and it works well, but I don't have a physical printer, so I can't test that.

Answer (score 15):

I just added a <kbd>right-click</kbd> menu option that allows you to select multiple files, select *Script* → *pdf-printer.sh* and it'll create PDF files. If you choose another printer name in the script, it should use that instead, but I can't verify that. Older how-tos might not work because we've moved to GNOME 3 which has a few changes. In this case, scripts have been moved from `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` to `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`. Otherwise, everything should work as you would expect.

1. Install http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cups-pdf. This package provides a PDF printer that prints to the PDF folder in your home folder, `$HOME/PDF`.
2. Open Nautilus and create a folder named `PDF` in your `home`.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> in Nautilus to show hidden files.
4. Open `~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts`.
5. Create a new file and call it `pdf-printer.sh`.
6. Paste the following:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   # pdf-printer.sh
   #
   # Print files from the right-click context menu in Nautilus.
   # Place this script in ~/.local/share/nautilus/scripts.
   # The printer to use (as shown in the Printer Configuration
   # gui or in /etc/cups/printers.conf).
   printer=PDF
   echo "$NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS" | while read file
       do
           lpr -P "$printer" "$file"
   done
   exit 0
   ```
7. Save the file and close it.
8. <kbd>right-click</kbd> the file and choose *Properties* → *Permissions*. Make sure the box is checked to allow executing the file.

It is possible that you have to restart Nautilus for this to work. In that case, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `r`. Should that not work, then you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `killall nautilus` or restart the system.

Other than that, you should now be able to select files, <kbd>right-click</kbd> and use the script from the *Script* menu.

Comment: To clarify what i tried to do: I wanted to printout about 10 pdf documents in oder to stick them in an envelope and snail mail them. As it was a sunny day i wanted to get done fast and not open each and every document in evince and print from there. The above solved the problem. With 3 remarks: 1. the script needs to sit here /home/[usr name]/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts im my case 2. printing i.e odt to pdf folder didnt work 3. but if you use printer=[Printername] (which you will find in the "printing" gui) then all the documents will be sent directly to the printer. Thanks! Appreciate the help.

Comment: Tusend takk og en hilsen til Oslo! Daniel

Comment: Glad to be of service. Please accept the answer so others can see that it was solved.

Comment: Having received an upvote today, I was curious to see if it still worked on Ubuntu 21.10, many years later. It does! That's nice. Note to self: it was written on a Sunday.